ERROR_BAD_PARAMETERS with 2Captcha while trying to solve FunCaptcha on LinkedIn
I'm trying to solve the Arkose FunCaptcha on LinkedIn with 2Captcha. I'm using Selenium, and here's my Python code.
try:
    captcha = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='captchaSiteKey']")
    iframe = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe')
  
    site_key = captcha.get_attribute('value')
    url = iframe.get_attribute('src')
  
    print(f"Solving captcha for site key: {site_key}")
    print(f"URL: {url}")
    
    result = self.solver.funcaptcha(site_key, url)
    if result.get('code') == 0:
        token = result.get('token')
        self.driver.execute_script(
            f"document.querySelector('input[name=\"fc-token\"]').value = '{token}';"
        )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error solving captcha: {str(e)}")
finally:
    self.driver.switch_to.default_content()

I successfully get a site key, and the URL is https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/challenge/funCaptchaInternal. However, I'm getting ERROR_BAD_PARAMETERS. Why is this happening?
